# Is it possible to replace placeholders from one configuration source with values from another in Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration, environment-variables, config

Let's say I have JSON configuration files where multiple entries have placeholders like these:

```js
"fooUri": "https://{DOMAIN}/api/fooResource",
"userId": "{USER_GROUP}_{USER_NAME}"
```

I'd like to replace the `{PLACEHOLDERS}` with values from other configuration sources, e.g. environmental variables.

Right now, the easiest way I see is to:

1. Build an `IConfiguration` from the JSON files.
2. Build a separate `IConfiguration` from environmental variables.
3. Recursively iterate through all values in the first configuration and replace the placeholders with values from the second.

Is there a simpler way to do this easily with the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration API?
Support for automatic replacement in case of JSON file change would also be nice.